# How to Use An Escape URL String With Formatting in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, escaping

I need to gather data from a website based on the user's input.

searchString is the user inputted value, such as "search this string".

```
NSString *withoutSpaces = [searchString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

Here, I need to replace spaces with %20

Next, I need to put the new string without spaces (replaced with %20) into another string.

```
NSString *unescapedSearchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"website.com/query?=%22%@%22", withoutSpaces];
```

The site I need is not really "website.com", but that's just an example. I also need the %22 to remain at the beginning and end.

As you can see, I need the %@ to format the new withoutSpaces user input into the website URL.

I did a search and found examples but I could not find any with formatting such as in my case using %@.

What's the best way to "escape" the characters and keep my formatted string? Currently, when I try to access data from the website, it comes back as null. However, when I try a string without the %@ formatting and an actual value, I successfully retrieve the data from a website.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does it matter if the URL is created with a formatted string literal?  You can escape it all the same.

Comment: I need to use stringWithFormat in order to include %@ but the %22 and & are also interfering.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should do things this way:

```
NSString *searchString = ... // the raw search string with spaces and all
NSString *quoted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", searchString];
NSString *escaped = [quoted stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"website.com?query=%@&value=all", escaped];
```

BTW - the URL seems a little off. There should be a variable name before the `=` and after the `?`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I need "?query=%22" before the searchString. I need "%22&value=all" after the searchString. So it should look like "?query=%22test%20search%22&value=all".

Comment: Edit: I believe I got it to work by instead of using stringWithFormat, I just appended the withoutSpaces to the beginning of the website string and then added the end of the website string to that. I can now get the website data successfully without having to deal with formatting issues.

Comment: See my update answer. I update the URL to meet your first comment. The code I posted gives you what you want including the quotes and everything being properly escaped.

Comment: Thanks, your updated one works also. I don't understand how it works without %22s, but in the console it shows up with the %22s (which is the proper format I need). Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: Look at how I create the `escaped` string. That's where all of the %XX values come from.

Comment: Oh okay. Once again, thanks. I'll mark yours as correct answer.